# Can I get the Enterprise Settings via the REST API?

Tags: box-api

My Enterprise Account in Box has some Enterprise settings, like the password policy.  Can I retrieve those settings using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only get the settings for each individual user, not general enterprise settins:

http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-the-current-users-information-2